# Transient properties in Firebase

Tags: firebase

Is it possible to "declare" transient properties in Firebase objects?

I want to bind a Firebase collection to $scope.messages, but some of the objects in $scope.messages are just for decoration and should not be persisted, and I would like to avoid having an extra Javascript array for display purposes since that requires explicit handling to keep it in sync with Firebase.

Comment: Check out [AngularFire](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/) and [extending the services](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide/extending-services.html). You could modify the $save and $add methods to do anything you like, such as look for a private property like `if( !rec._ignoreMe ) { return $firebaseArray.prototype.$save.apply(this, arguments); }`